# django comments app fails to show form

Tags: python, django

After reading about the django comments framework i was about to implement it, so i installed it in my settings.py file and started using the template tags (im using django 1.6, i know its deprecated but it should work for what im going to use it for).

When trying to use the

```
{% get_comment_form for <object> as <var %}
```

and then using it im getting this error:
Reverse for 'django.contrib.comments.views.comments.post_comment' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

I searched around and troubleshooted the problem and i did find a couple of people having the same problem, but they had added a $ to the line they had configured in urls.py or they just had the same configuration i had, after they had fixed the problem.

When troubleshooting ive found out that this seems to be related to the capturing of values in my urls.py file (in the line shown below) but i need to capture that value in order to show the correct arcticle so i cant just remove it.

I'm trying to implement comments for the Story object, and this is my relevant part of urls.py:

```
url(r'^story/display/(?P<specific_story>\d+)/$', 'base.views.display_story', name='display_story'),
url(r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls'))
```

This is the view:

```
def display_story(request, specific_story):
    """ Display details for a specific story. """
    story_details = Story.objects.get(id=specific_story)
    story_votes = story_details.votes
    picture = story_details.picture

    return render(request, "base/story/display_story.html", {
                    'story_details': story_details,
                    'story_votes': story_votes
        })
```

And this is the part of the template code where im using the template tag:

```
{% get_comment_form for experience_details as form %}
<table>
  <form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post">
        <input type="submit" name="preview" value="Preview">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need RequestContext for the templatetags.
This problem raised because the template cannot render correctly as some variables are missing.

You can import RequestContext by:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.templates.context import RequestContext

def display_story(request, specific_story):

    this_view_context = {
                'story_details': story_details,
                'story_votes': story_votes
                }
    request_context = RequestContext(request, this_view_context)
    return render_to_response( "base/story/display_story.html", request_context)
```

You can use render_to_response or render, it's your choice

Comment: Thanks for answering but this isnt correct. If you only use render instead of render_to_response you will get a render context with it like ive done and you dont need to explicitly add a RequestContext so that should not be the problem. After more troubleshooting i moved the app out of the current apps scope and placed the configuration directly in the global urls.py, then it worked but i havent found the cause for the problem yet.